# How to make each application have its own audio monitor in pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I want to record two live video streams (rtmp flash videos in a browser) at the same time and I'm running two instances of the SimpleScreenRecorder for that. Each instance records a different region on the screen. The only problem is sound. I use separate browsers so each browser has its own audio playback in pulseaudio.

[image]

How can I separate playbacks so that each playback stream will have a separate pulseaudio monitor? I have only "Monitor of Built-In Audio Analog Stereo", but I need two monitors, one for Firefox and one for Chrome.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it using Jack audio server   :

- Install jackd and qjackctl : say "yes" when asked to have real time access right, then reboot to apply this access right.
- Stop temporarily pulseaudio with this 3 commands :
  `mkdir ~/.pulse`
  `echo autospawn=no > ~/.pulse/client.conf`
  `pulseaudio -k`

(Later, to revert to pulseaudio normal mode, run `echo autospawn=yes > ~/.pulse/client.conf` then `pulseaudio` )

- create .asoundrc  (the point is important) in your home dir containing :

> > pcm.!default { 
> >         type plug   slave { pcm "jack" } 
> >     }
> >
> > pcm.jack {   type jack
> >     playback_ports {
> >           0 system:playback_1
> >           1 system:playback_2   }
> >     capture_ports {
> >           0 alsa_pcm:capture_1
> >           1 alsa_pcm:capture_2   }   }
> >
> > ctl.mixer0 {   type hw   card 1 }

- Run qjackctl from sound menu, click "start", click  "connect" to display "connections" windows.
- Launch 2 differents SimpleScreenRecorder , chose "jack" as audio , start preview mode to display vumeter in both
- Launch Firefox and Chrome, play video in each
- Go to qjackctl   "connections" windows , drag and drop   from  the first left side "jack-alsa-xxx" to  the first right side  "simplescreenrecorder": you will get a connection displayed and vumeter will move in the first simplescreenrecorder. 
  Do the same for the second "jack-alsa" and "simplescreenrecorder"
- Now you can record  audio from each browser in each simplescreenrecorder

May be Firefox has problem with html5 and jack audio server in youtube,  I have only tested with flashplayer.
[image: qjackctl]

Comment: there is no `/.pulse/client.conf` in Ubuntu 14.04 Do I need to create it?

Comment: right, i edited the answers to add mkdir ~/.pulse