# Routing audio from two different browsers using qjackctl and JACK

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, jack

(first post here, apologize in advance for any formatting problems etc.)

Hi all,

I'm trying to route audio from Chrome and Firefox as two separate streams into Supercollider so that I can mix them separately. Right now I've been successful in routing all app sound to a pulseaudio sink which I can then route to SC (using the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572120/how-to-use-jack-and-pulseaudio-alsa-at-the-same-time-on-the-same-audio-device)), but this means that all app audio is summed before getting to SC so I can't edit the streams separately.

I'm relatively new to Linux audio so have mostly been stumbling around various posts on here to try and see if this is possible. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/526894/how-to-make-each-application-have-its-own-audio-monitor-in-pulseaudio?fbclid=IwAR1nNpubdrTnh6_K33WscnIQbbILvdEXTkSj6E9OvXfXMg4ZFCu48_jELx4) seemed promising, but I couldn't get it to work. This might be because Chrome and Firefox now use pulseaudio instead of alsa as their default? Any ideas would be much appreciated!

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and using qjackctl and jackd2, hopefully with all the correct libraries installed.

Image of my qjackctl session (I'd basically like each browser to have its own 'pulseaudio jack sink'):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVxOx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use command

```
pactl load-module module-jack-sink sink_name=voip_in client_name=voip_in
```

you should get 2nd sink loaded called 'Pulseaudio Jack Sink 01' available in QjackCtl

command can be added to QjackCtl 'Execute script after startup' to load 2nd sink automatically when JACK is started

Also need to change one of the browsers to use new sink in `pavucontrol --tab 1` from drop-down list of playback outputs

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing exactly this and got it working :) The next step is connecting the second browser to the second sink without using the pavucontrol gui (IE with a script).

Comment: if you only use 2nd browser connected to 2nd sink, pavucontrol usually remembers manual setting when used again.